# how to fetch a value from multidimensional array using foreach in codeiginiter

Tags: multidimensional-array

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => Female
                [type] => radio
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => Male
                [type] => radio
            )

    )
```

How to fetch field_name and type value from this array using foreach loop?

Comment: What's keeping you from achieving this? Can't you simply use foreach loop you the way you use it otherwise, and access the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($outerArray as $array){
    foreach($array as $item){
        echo $item->field_name;
        echo $item->type;
    }
}
```